# How to iterate over a function which results in typeError?

Tags: python, selenium

```
class Lion(BasePage):
    log = cl.customLogger(logging.DEBUG)  
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

    csvreaderNew = '/Users/r/Documents/LionCSVfileOLD.csv'
    csvreaderOld = '/Users/r/Documents/LionCSVfileNEW.csv'

    def oldFileList(self):
        return [l[12] for l in self.csvreaderOld]

    def newFileList(self):
        return [l[12] for l in self.csvreaderNew]

    url_list = [item for item in oldFileList() if item not in newFileList() ]
```

I have two functions oldFileList() and newFileList() which return a list but when I try to get a new list "url_list " I get a  TypeERROR: oldFileList() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 4):

You need to call your methods with `self` in the same way you need to with variables when you're referring to a method elsewhere within the class that has the method.

```
url_list = [item for item in self.oldFileList() if item not in self.newFileList() ]
```

Comment: I tried that before and I get the   NameError: name 'self' is not defined
error.
I created another function     def url_list(self):
        return [item for item in self.oldFileList() if item not in self.newFileList()]
but when I call this function in a different Test Class with a for loop "for url in self.fl.url_list:" it is not expecting a ()

Answer (score 1):

You need to use those methods like `self.oldFileList` and `self.newFileList` and move that variable definition to `__init__`

Also, check out different kinds of constant definitions here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-variable-outside-and-inside-the-class-and-method/

Comment: I tried that before and I get the NameError: name 'self' is not defined error.

Comment: yeah you need to move that line inside __init__ method so it has access to self. Like this, 
`class Lion(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        # super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver
        url_list = [item for item in self.oldFileList() if item not in self.newFileList() ]
        print("url_list:", url_list)`